# UIViewController: Is there a way to know when the modal transition animation is finished?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

In my app, I have a UIViewController presented modally with the default slide animation - let's call it 'A'.  During the time 'A' is busy popping up it's possible another piece of code will try to use A to present a further modal viewcontroller.
On these occasions, I get an exception, presumably as 'A' isn't fully ready yet.

Does anyone know if there's a way of knowing if a UIViewController is still animating?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the modal animation the method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

will be called. That's the indication that the animation is finished and there you can set a variable like

```
animationFinished = YES;
```